# How to backup Windows 8 recovery partion from linux?

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery

My windows 8 does not boot any more (I get an error message),
But I still have the recovery partion, so before I mess every thing even more, I want to backup my recovery.

Answer (score 1):

My real quick answer would be to use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org). It's free and it allows you to save a single partition or an entire disk to a USB drive or external hard drive.